# What is the right way to set CORS headers for a single API in Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

There is a ton of info on how to set CORS headers to allow origins on all requests in bottle, primarily using the Hooks plugin and using 'after-request'. (https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html)

However, I have 10 routes, and I only want to enable CORS requests on one of them. Is there a way to do this with the hooks plugin ?

If not, should I implement the OPTIONS method for a particular route ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one route, why not just apply the CORS header to that one route?  You could also use a decorator class to add the header to any routes you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should create general route like below to intercept any request for method OPTIONS and then add a hook to apply CORS headers to all requests:

```
import bottle

# This route capture all route for method OPTIONS
@bottle.route('/<:re:.*>', method='OPTIONS')
def cors():
    pass

headers = ['Origin', 'Accept', 'Content-Type',
           'X-Requested-With', 'X-CSRF-Token',
           'Authorization']
HEADERS = ', '.join((headers + [h.lower() for h in headers]))

# For all request I add cors headers
def apply_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = HEADERS

app = bottle.default_app()
app.add_hook('after_request', apply_cors)
```